# How prevent objects from snapping back into position in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice, libreoffice-writer, drag-and-drop, libreoffice-impress

How can I disable this super-annoying "feature" causing objects (e.g. a drawn rectangle) to snap back into its original position when doing drag & drop? I simply want to translate a rectangle by only a very small amount in order to highlight something on an image, but hitting the cursor keys shifts it by a whole centimeter or more and when trying to carefully drag it using the mouse one cannot translate it by less than ~3-4 mm, because it will snap back to its original position when getting close to it. It's one of those features that helps exactly 0% and annoys 100% of users...

Alternatively, how can one decrease the step size for translating objects with the cursor keys? Obviously, 1 cm or more is way too coarse to be in any way useful.

Comment: have you tried holding one of the modifier keys?

Answer (score 0):

I also haven't found a way to do this... my workaround is zooming in a lot, so that the effective snap threshold (which seems to be based on visual distance on screen) becomes smaller relative to the shapes I'm positioning.